# Recover a dropped MySQL database with its procedures

Tags: mysql, recovery

I had some databases on a server and MySQL server on this server has been uninstalled accidentally by someone.

I had some backups on this server and could recover all tables and their data successfully, but the problem is that the events and procedures are lost.

How can I recover the lost events and procedures? I searched a lot to know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky, you won't need the backups.  (Oops, you have already gone beyond this step.)

If MySQL's data directory was left behind by the uninstall, then simply reinstall.

Was the backup taken using mysqldump (either explicitly, or under-the hood)?  If so, perhaps it failed to have the arguments asking to save "stored routines", etc.

I fear you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from a comment on the question by [Michael - sqlbot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/11651/michael-sqlbot)*</sub>

In the future, you will want to add the `--events` and `--routines` options to your backups... and take away the access "someone" has to your database server.  Unless the files are still there in spite of the "uninstall," the data is, for all practical purposes, lost... with the possible exception of low, low, low level forensic-style recovery of the delete file contents.